# session id changes when using redirect() in View

Tags: django, apache, django-views, mod-wsgi, django-sessions

I have a page with a form that I use for site search. The form uses POST verb to submit data to search for. The search results are displayed under the form after it is submitted.

In an attempt to solve the "Page has expired" problem on IE I use the so called PRG pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). so I return django.shortcuts.redirect() from my view's post() method that redirects to the same URL.

The problem is that in production I see different session ids associated with the GET requests sent after the 302 response. and since I store my form in the session to be able to split the results in to pages, I get inconsistent results.

I run django under apache/mod_wsgi. apache is configured to run at most 3 processes.

It does not happen right after I restart httpd, and it seems that it starts happening after the amount of memory consumed by httpd processes reaches some limit.

I check this by repeatedly pressing the submit button, the form gets populated from the session so I can see the search strings that I have entered. when session changes, the form is returned blank. so, when this starts happening, the form gets successfully populated 2 times in a row, and when I press submit for the third time it returns blank, which means that the server returned new session cookies. this seems to have something to do with the ServerLimit setting.

What is wrong? Any ideas?

thanks

Konstantin

Comment: Do you get the same behavior across all browsers?  I wonder if IE does something weird when it gets a permanent redirect vs a temporary one.  Why would you want to use a permanent redirect?  Isn't that effectively saying "From now on all posts should be made to the final GET page"?

Comment: I have edited my question. the problem occurs with http 302 as well.

Comment: I've run into the same issue.  What Antivirus/Network Security Suite do you use?

Comment: I just have a windows vista with the standard firewall enabled, I do not have any additional software.

Comment: When you say you see a different session - what are you referring to?

Comment: I see a different session cookie set on the 302 response. it does not happen every time. only intermittently. and I know that the previous session could not have expired when this happens.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a HTTP 303 See Other response instead of a 302?

http://tumblr.jonthornton.com/post/7902581999/preventing-form-re-submission-with-http-303-redirects

Answer (score 1):

You are Using Django Sessions App Correct?

If that is the case then it stores the current session ID in a cookie whose name is specified with the setting `SESSION_COOKIE_NAME` and it defaults to sessionid. Since you are not experiencing this issue in Firefox, I believe it should be safe to assume that your session handling and storage within Django is working fine.

The most likely culprit here is that IE is losing/deleting the sessionid cookie, causing it start a new session after the redirect. A quick google on the subject seems to confirm this.

You can see some related information at:

- http://www.persistall.com/archive/2008/01/25/cookies--redirects--nightmares.aspx
- http://jhottengineering.blogspot.com/2009/02/ie-post-and-redirect-errors.html

Now, in order to actually solve your problem. Django does not set a session cookie unless it actually needs too (i.e. If you set Session Data). If the only place you set session data is in the view when you POST, then IE is going to discard the cookie setting the sessionid.

So a quick and simple bandaid would be to just save some junk data (or default values?) to the session during the GET to display the form originally before the POST, that will IE will get the sessionid cookie, and things should work.

Comment: thanks. at first I thought that this is an IE only problem. but since I saw it in Firefox as well, I believe there is something wrong with the server setup. so I edited my question, and now it does not mention IE. I ended up with changing POST to GET since it is used for search anyway... Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 0):

IE opens a new connection when it gets a 302 redirect.  This is why the 302 solves your page has expired problem. But that also means you are serving a new "session".

You'll need some other mechanism to track the session across the 302 other than being dependent upon the connection.

Comment: thanks. do you mean IE opens a new connection on 301? it seems to work on 302. also, it does no seem to open a new connection always, because I do get the same session across several 301s in a row.

Comment: I have edited my question. the problem occurs with http 302 as well.

Comment: IE should still be sending the same cookies over either connection, though.